# Django fails to find static files served by nginx

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I know this is a really noobish question but I can't find any solution despite finding the problem trivial.

I have a django application deployed with gunicorn. The static files are served by the nginx server with the following url : `myserver.com/static/admin/css/base.css`. However, my django application keep looking for the static files at `myserver.com:8001/static/admin/css/base.css` and is obviously failing (404).

I don't know how to fix this. Is it a django or an nginx problem ? Here is my nginx configuration file :

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/myproject/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you have this in your configuration. It doesn't do anything.

```
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
```

Anyway, you are not passing on the `Host` header, which is the most likely reason I can think of why your URLs are being mangled.

Try setting that:

```
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Comment: The first line you mentionned is part of the nginx configuration file recommended in the digitalocean tutorial, I just copied/pasted it. What you have suggested didn't change anything. Is it an nginx of django problem ? Should nginx serve the files on port 8001 or should django serve files from myserver.com instead of myserver.com:8001 ?

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that you have debug disabled in your settings.py

`DEBUG = False`

Check your path to static files and url (ex.)

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = {
  "/home/myproject/static/",
}`

Define your static url in nginx (ex):

`location /static/ {
 alias /home/myproject/static/;
 expires 1d;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Is not django problem at, but nginx proxy configuration

The problem is quite similar to this one:
(I paste link directly as it is an internal link on serverfault, don't want to duplicate answers)

[Removing port from nginx redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/709037/removing-port-from-nginx-redirect/709073#709073)

Maybe even adding `proxy_redirect off;` to the `location` configuration does the trick.