# Removing port from nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress, django

I have a domain so www.mysite.com running app Django. In this server I created a Blog with WordPress. www.mysite.com/blog

Nginx Django app:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /blog {       
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  
    }
}
```

Nginx WordPress:

```
server {
    listen: 8000;
    root /var/www/html/blog;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    [......]

}
```

If I type www.mysite.com/blog show me page 404.
If I type www.mysite.com:8000 show me index WordPress.
How I remove port ":8000" the url thus leaving wwww.mysite.com/blog and show me index WordPress??

Comment: Why do you have two different `server` blocks? All of this should be in a single `server`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer of what you are looking for is in `proxy_redirect` option, after proxy_pass.

This nginx configuration sample can be useful:
(Take a look on proxy redirect line)

```
location /one/ {
proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;
proxy_redirect http://upstream:port/two/ /one/;
```

I think adding this should do the trick:

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000 /blog;
```

You can find full documentation and examples in the nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)